# How to properly use Google API Client on Glass XE22

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk, wear-os, google-api-client

I'm currently trying to use the following code to create an ApiClient connection

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

but in

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed");
    mGoogleApiClient.reconnect();
}
```

I'm getting this:

```
ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null}
```

If I'm reading correctly [in the manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes.html#SERVICE_INVALID), this corresponds to the version of Play being wrong to begin with.

As such, am I missing something from properly connecting running the code on Glass or this is not supported yet?

To give you a rough idea of what I want to do, I want to implement [this example](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Play Services is not supported on Glass at this time. This is currently being tracked as [issue 176](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=176) in our issue tracker, so you can follow that for more info in the future.

Comment: Hi Tony. Thanks for your answer. I've seen however that it's now possible to have Glass connect to the phone as Wear device and the push notifications will sync nicely between the two of them. I take it that's a very custom build solution in place for that then?